# How to put term payload pairs to a lucene document

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I have a list of terms and associated payloads. How can I put these into a lucene document or rather a field?

Here is my list:

```
List<MyTerm> list = new List<MyTerm>(){
 new MyTerm(){
  Text = "apple",
  Payload = BitConverter.GetBytes(2)
 },
 new MyTerm(){
  Text = "juice",
  Payload = BitConverter.GetBytes(5)
 }};
```

I guess I have to use the following constructor of a field.

```
Field(string name, TokenStream tokenStream);
```

But how to build the required tokenStream from my list?

**Edit**

I want to search by terms. The payloads are needed for custom scoring.

My terms are dominant colors of an image and I want to store the percentage of that color for scoring when searching by colors. If someone searches for red images, images with a lot red in it should be scored higher then images with less red in it.

**Edit**

I should mention, that one image can have mulitiple dominant colors. Furthermore I want to be able to search for images by multiple dominant colors. For example: I want to retrieve images which have a lot red and a lot blue. Thus I guess putting colors and intensities into different fields is not an option.

Comment: How do you want to search? Only on the terms or only on payload or on both?
What is your desired result? Do you want to find the payload by searching for the term?

Comment: I want to search by terms. The payloads are needed for custom scoring.

My terms are dominant colors of an image and I want to store the percentage of that color for scoring when searching by colors. If someone searches for red images, images with a lot red in it should be scored higher then images with less red in it.

Answer (score 0):

OK, based on your explanation I would suggest using 2 Fields - one for the term (dominant color) and one for the payload (intensity of color) - and sort the results on payload. This could look like this:

```
Field color = new Field("Color", colorString, Field.Store.No, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
Field intensity = new Field("Intensity", intensityString, Field.Store.No, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
```

The `color` field is used for querying, `intensity` for sorting.

If you want to, store the values in the index. Depends on your further needs.

BTW: Please use the edit function to update your original question with your additional information.